# Unable to load the following extension file: ext.detour_pro.php

Tags: ee2

A friend ask me to do some changes on his site made from EE. I never done any work in EE in my life so my first instinct is to copy all the files and database to my localhost. so that I can play it first in my local server before applying the changes on the live site. I'm using  xammp 1.8.1 (PHP version is 5.2.9).

So basically what i did is put all the files in c:\xammp\htdocs\thesite and the database in "dbee" then apply changes in config.php and database.php under expressionengine folder.

in config.php

```
$config['app_version'] = "272";
$config['install_lock'] = "";
$config['license_number'] = "";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['cp_url'] = 'http://localhost/thesite/admin.php';
$config['doc_url'] = "http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/";
$config['is_system_on'] = "y";
$config['allow_extensions'] = "y";
$config['site_label'] = 'sitel label';
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = 'c:\xammp\htdocs\thesite\assets\templates';

// Third Party Prefs
$config['third_party_path'] = 'c:\xammp\htdocs\thesite\assets\add-ons\third_party';
$config['url_third_themes'] = 'http://localhost/thesite/assets/add-ons/themes/';
$config['enable_online_user_tracking'] = "n";
$config['enable_hit_tracking'] = "n";
$config['enable_entry_view_tracking'] = "n";
$config['dynamic_tracking_disabling'] = "";

// END EE config items
```

in database.php

```
$db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['expressionengine']['username'] = 'root';
$db['expressionengine']['password'] = 'pwd';
$db['expressionengine']['database'] = 'dbee';
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
$db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = 'c:/xammp/htdocs/thesite/app/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';
```

and the results are;

from index.php and admin.php

[image: index.php]

[image: admin.php]

from index.php
from admin.php
I already look in google can't find a solution.

I am hoping I could get answer from you guys.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the [Detour Pro extension](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/detour-pro) is installed, but the package is missing from **thesite\assets\add-ons\third_party**.

If the package is indeed there, then EE is having trouble finding and loading files from that directory (which is where third party add-ons are stored).

Comment: Thank you @Derek for your reply! Yes the folder **detour_pro** is in the **third_party** folder. The live site is working, I just copy all the files and database to my localhost. What do you think is problem?

Comment: aside from config.php and database.php which file should I still need to update? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ensure all the Detour Pro files are in BOTH folders - Detour Pro has a theme folder (where the css & images reside) and obviously the add-on folder (where the extension PHP files reside). Also check that the correct ownership is on that folder and permissions (compare with other add-ons). Try disabling the extension (or all extenstions) to see if the issue goes away.